# Linear Algebra Problem - columns of $A$ are linearly independent $\Rightarrow$ $A^TA$ non-singular

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to go in this direction only. Is this proof correct? ($A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix).

I am considering the contrapositive of the statement:

Suppose $A^TA$ is singular. 
Then $\det (A^TA) =0$. 
$\det(A^TA) = \det(A^T) \det(A)$ and since $\det (A^T) = \det(A)$, we must have $det(A) = 0$. In other words, the columns of $A$ are linearly dependent.   $\blacksquare$

Comment: It appears that you're assuming that $A$ is square.  This is not given...

Comment: How do you define the determinant of a non-square matrix?

Comment: Oh, I see, didn't see that :(. How should I approach this then?

Comment: Rank(A'A)=rank(A)=n when A is a real non-singular matrix of order n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that
$$
    A^TA v\cdot v = Av \cdot Av = \Vert Av \Vert^2
$$
So if $A^TA v= 0$, what does this tell you about $Av$?

Comment: got it - cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Note that $A^{T}Av =0 \implies Av \in \ker A^{T} \cap \text{Image}(A) =\{0\}$.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/813275)

Comment: A partially correct answer with details left to the OP should not be discouraged. In fact, if the OP understands why the null space of $A^{T}$ is an orthogonal complement of the range of $A$, then this hint gives a complete answer along the line of using contrapositive argument just as the OP attempted.

Comment: Actually I am not sure what is the correct behavior, but for me the *answer section* is for answers. A hint, especially of this length, can be given as a comment. Maybe someone familiar with the SE mechanics can clarify this. However, this might not be the correct review response and I am sorry, but it was my choice because of a lack of a better option in the menu.